# Conversion Error : ArrayBuffer to Int16Array

Tags: javascript, firefox, arraybuffer

this should be straight forward, but I am not sure why I am getting the error, I am using constructor with ArrayBuffer as parameter as shown in [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Int16Array), but I am getting the error as invalid arguments, (p.s with dataview I have checked, the data is Int16 only)

the code is:

```
        var view= DataView(arrayBuf);
        console.log('arrayBuf.byteLength : '+arrayBuf.byteLength);
        console.log('data at 0 : '+view.getInt16(0));
        console.log('data at 1 : '+view.getInt16(1));
        var int16arry = new Int16Array(arrayBuf);
```

the console output is:

```
"arrayBuf.byteLength : 117" 
"data at 0 : 22720" 
"data at 1 : -16315"
Error: invalid arguments
```

what is my mistake?

Comment: Hmm, an array of 16 bit ints should always have an even number of bytes. If you try to calculate how many int16 you have in your arrayBuffer you end up with 58,5 ints, and that wont work. What else have you padded in there? If you do in fact have different data types that i have a script for you if you want it

Comment: @Snellface unfortunately these arraybuffers are what I recieve from a library which has no documentation,  these are encoded packets, and they work fine when I individually copy them using DataView, also i do not understand how, length of packet/Int16Array is ```117``` and not ```117/2```, that y i am increasing ```view.getInt16(0)```, as 0,1,2, and not `,2,4...

Comment: arrayBuf.byteLength gives you the number of bytes in the buffer regardless of their type. So your buffer is either not received correctly, or it contains something other then "only" 16bit integers. If you loop through them one by one and extract them with getInt16, can you make sure that the data you are getting is actually what you are expecting to get? After you have read the final "full" int16, try reading an int8 and see what you get?

Comment: Ps, you could try this: var int16arry = new Int16Array(arrayBuf, 0, Math.floor(arrayBuf.byteLength / 2)); This will remove the last "half" 16bit int in the end, but i would call that a hack since you do not know why there is an extra byte, and what it is used for :P You can read this in the documentation you linked, but the function i used here take these arguments: Int16Array(buffer, start index, number of entries to read);

Comment: Btw, what library are you using? Or more specifically what language is it written in? (If you are using a javascript library you can probably look at the source code of the function which gives you your array buffer, and that might give you a clue as to why you are receiving an extra byte)

Comment: @Snellface the hack works, i think you are right, the problem is caused by the odd length, thanks.

Comment: @Snellface using opus.js, it is C code turned into JS code if i am correct, https://github.com/kazuki/opus.js-sample

Comment: which function do you use to get your array buffer?

Comment: Like, you do something like var arrayBuf = <what have you written here>?

Comment: Array of packets would be returned by encoded packets(ArrayBuffer) is returned by opus.worker.js (method encode_i16(pcm)), this happens when encode a wav file, what i am trying to do is compressing a wav file before uploading to server.

Comment: I have tried reading the documentation but i am unable to see/understand why you get that error, and since i do not have any wav files to try this with i can't set up a test for myself (I also need to get back to my work ;P). I do not think you will make your audio decoder/encoder work if you have to "hack" it just to make the data the correct size, and my guess is that either something is wrong with the library (for example, there were some functions/methods in the opus source which contained to actual code..), or that the data is correct, but contains other information as well (bad docs..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that your arrayBuffer is in the wrong size. You can use:

```
var int16Array = new Int16Array(arrayBuf, 0, Math.floor(arrayBuf.byteLength / 2));
```

to **hack** away the problem.

**Case specific comment:**
I have tried reading the source for your library but i am unable to see why you are getting that extra byte (or what is missing).
The data you are getting is supposed to be 16 bit ints but for some reason you have other data there that take up an uneven amount of bytes, and according to the source as far as i can tell there should be some doubles (javascript floats) in there as well, meaning that "hacking" away the problem might not work.

Comment: I found the solution to the problem, used ```UInt8Array```, it would take care of the odd/even problem, thx for the time spent on this.

Comment: Do you still get the correct values? The name of the function you told me that you use implies that it will use 16bit ints ("_i16" at the end of the name) Great if it works anyways!